# How to automate filtering rows by columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe as follows:

```
df =

COL_1   COL_2   VAL_1
ABC     AAA     ABC
CDE     CDE     RTY
ABC     ABC     RTY
ABC     RTY     DEF
```

I want to caculate the number of rows containing any unique value from columns starting with `COL`: `COL_1` and `COL_2` (`VAL_1` should not be used).

The expected result is:

```
GROUP   COUNT
ABC     3
CDE     2
RTY     1
AAA     1
```

One possibility is to manually specify column names and calculate the number of rows also manually specifying all possible values for `GROUP`. But obviously this solution is not good if the number of columns and values in `GROUP` is large.

How to do it automatically? I think that the approach should be to filter all rows that have tunique values for columns starting with `COL`?

I tried this, but it takes a long time on a dataset of 1Gb and it gives some incorrect result. Also I don't know how to avoid specifying the values of `GROUP`: `str.contains('ABC')`.

```
t_cols = [c for c in df.columns.values if not c.startswith('COL')]
aa = df.drop(t_cols,axis=1)
aa.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('ABC').any(), axis=1).shape
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you can use `value_counts()`:

```
df.filter(regex = "^COL").stack().value_counts()

#ABC    4
#CDE    2
#AAA    1
#RTY    1
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: yeah, this solution is better! :)

Comment: That's a nice solution. By the way do you know how to add conditions to this code? I mean what if I need to count rows, also considering that the value of column `VAL_1` is equal to `ABC`?

Comment: If you mean count the number of rows you have, you can use `shape[0]`, and also use logical index to select rows with conditions. The syntax would be something like `df[df.VAL_1 == "ABC"].filter(regex="^COL").shape[0]`  depending on what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I've just noticed that this solution calculates all occurances of value within a row. For instance, in your case `ABC` is equal to 4, but it should be 3, because in the third row it appeared twice and should be calculated once. Sorry, I probably have not explained well myself. Could you please elaborate the answer?

Comment: How about the `CDE` then, should it be 1 also as both appear in the same row?

Comment: You can try this one, if you want drop duplicated elements for each row before counting. `df.filter(regex="^COL").stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index().drop_duplicates()[0].value_counts()`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
In [12]: df.filter(like='COL_').stack().to_frame('COL').groupby('COL').size()
Out[12]:
COL
AAA    1
ABC    4
CDE    2
RTY    1
dtype: int64
```